# Can Lists cause memory leaks if reinitialized with the "new" keyword?

Tags: java, list

I am trying to figure out if the following code could cause a memory leak.

```
public void example(List<object> list1) {  
    list1 = new ArrayList<objects>();    
}
```

If `list1` was passed with `data`, what happens to that `data` when `list1` is reassigned?
I know Java uses a garbage collector but is there any chance the old `list1` data can stay around?

Comment: If you overwrite the `list1` reference and there are no other references, then the GC will eventually take it. You can not cause a memory leak this way.

Comment: The old objects will be garbage collected unless they are referenced somewhere else like another collection object

Comment: When all references to a list are lost, it is eligible for garbage collection. If the list was the only object maintaining references to each of elements then they are also eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: In this case, though, note that `list1` is a parameter. This means that it is passed inside from a caller. The caller still has the original reference, and you are merely assigning a second list to the reference you have. So while the method is running, the old list is not going to be garbage collected.

Comment: the list used to call the method has nothing to do with the list assigned inside the method; the *old list1 data can stay around* as far it's referenced outside the method

Answer (score 0):

It *will* stay around, at least while `example` method is being executed.

What happens next completely depends on whether `list1` is still reachable in your code, outside the method. It's also possible that when you return from the method, the new `ArrayList` gets garbage collected and the old one (which was passed to the method) does not.